# How can i access a file uploaded to a SFTP server?

Tags: java

After we upload a file to a sftp site , I want to go that sftp site and check whether the file has been uploaded or not? So I wanted to know how we could access the sftp site from the address bar and look for the file. If my domain name is test.com how could I access it to check for the file?

Comment: What address bar?  If all you're looking to do is verify that the upload was successful, doesn't the SFTP client do that?  Can't you get the file list for the destination path and verify that the file is there?  If you're asking how to access the file from some other means, there's no way for us to know by what other means it might be available.  A web browser, perhaps?  Well, that depends on whether or not a web server provides access to the file.  If it does, you enter the address of the file and request it from the web server.  Which has nothing to do with SFTP.

Comment: FTP with Java: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: well I am new to uploading files through SFTP. When I was going through few documentations I came across somehting like, to access files uploaded to a ftp site use "ftp://test.com" so I wanted to know if there is something like sftp://test.com to access them when they are uploaded using sftp.

Comment: Use an ftp client software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftps://test.com would be my guess